# Replacement for switch statment

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
    if direction == 0: # Left
        moved = self.slideLeft()
    elif direction == 1: # Right
        moved = self.slideRigth()
    elif direction == 2: # Up
        moved = self.slideUp()
    elif direction == 3: # Down
        moved = self.slideDown()


    if(moved):
```

I know there is no swith statement in python but i am curious if there maybe is a nicer way to write this. Btw moved is just a Boolean

Comment: maybe create a `list` of these methods (or `dict`) and use the index (or key) like `moved = mylist[1]()` would be equivalent to `moved = self.slideRight()`

Comment: A thank you if will do that

Comment: Do you might know if your way is faster?

Comment: [ self.slideLeft, self.slideRight, self.slideUp, self.slideDown ][ direction ]()  would work without a dictionary for your specific use case.  In fact, you could create an array of movement functions in the class and use it directly: self.slide[ direction ]()

Comment: @Cing no idea if it's faster. haven't tested. if you have just 4 functions, and aren't calling them very often, performance shouldn't be an issue. Make sure you (and your team) use the one that is more readable :)